# How to make the QTableWidget size scale with the contents (PyQt5)?

Tags: python, pyqt5

How do i make my table window scale, so i dont have gaps on the side of it. I want it to scale with the size of the contents, and in this case the variable **myList** can have different amounts of items in it. Doing what i am now, leaves a ~20px gap between the edges of the table, and the edges of the widget

I would like to remove the inner border, so there is only a border between the widget and the window, but not between the table and the widget. But i dont know how.

[I want to remove the green area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byMMi.png) I left some unpainted so you can see it.

Here is the code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
import sys

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi()

    def setupUi(self):
        myList = ["Hello", "World", "!"]
        self.table = QTableWidget(self)
        self.table.setRowCount(3)
        self.table.setColumnCount(len(myList))

        for y, x in enumerate(myList):
            self.table.setItem(1, y, QTableWidgetItem(x))
        for x in range(self.table.columnCount()):
            self.table.setItem(2, x, QTableWidgetItem(""))
        self.table.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)

        self.main_widget = QWidget()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.main_widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        self.main_widget.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    M = Main()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I am using `self.table.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)` right now, but it doesn't seem to be doing the job.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the table to **always** have that size, no matter if the window is resized (possibly leaving some emtpy space if you don't have extending widgets)? And what should happen if the content of the table change? In any case, try using `self.table.setFixedSize(self.table.sizeHint())`, but **after** creating all its elements.